# Copy the line above using Word Find and Replace

Tags: replace, find, cpu-word

i want to find whats comes after the  ":" in the "x:" and copy it to "y:"
So lets say i have
*Using wildcards

```
x:hello my friends thanks for helping me
y:

x:Thank you very much
y:
```

how can i use Find and Replace to copy it so the outcome will be

```
x:hello my friends thanks for helping me
y:hello my friends thanks for helping me

x:Thank you very much
y:Thank you very much
```

Comment: I think its possible with regex to select all those text. To use regex Go to Home > Search > Advanced Seach > "Use Wildcards". But I do stuff like this all the time using VSCode... I recommend it, its extremely easy. (1) Open the file in VSCode, select "x:" and CTRL+D till all instances are selected. (2) Copy only the RHS of the colon (3) Use the arrow keys to come to "y:" and paste it. Hardly takes a couple of seconds

Comment: i need to use wildcards

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow but would be an appropriate question in another forum such as Microsoft Answers http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word, Super User https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word, or Word Forum http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/  What is an appropriate topic? https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic